# Computing matrix vector multiplication for each time point in two DataArrays

Tags: python-xarray

I have movement data containing head position vectors (x,y,z) and head rotation matrices (3x3). For each time point I have one of each. They are stored in two DataArrays like this:

```
pos = np.random.sample((1000, 3))
pos_data = xr.DataArray(pos, dims=('time', 'h_pos'), coords={'h_pos': ['x', 'y', 'z']})

rot = np.random.sample((1000, 3, 3))
rot_data = xr.DataArray(rot, dims=('time', 'h_rot_i', 'h_rot_j'))
```

How can I calculate the rotated position vector for each time point that I get by multiplying the position vector by the rotation matrix?

With pure numpy, I could use:

```
rotated = np.einsum('tij,tj->ti', rot, pos)
```

The documentation says xarray.dot is like np.einsum, but I can't make it work. Also the dims are not the same, in the einsum there are two i's, but the dims are h_rot_i for the matrices and h_pos for the position vectors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename the `h_rot_j` dimension to `h_pos` (or the other way around) so the names match. Then you also will need specify `dims='time'` in `dot` to explicitly preserve the time dimension.

In theory, the following should work, but it currently raises an error due to an [xarray bug](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2283):

```
>>> rot_data2 = rot_data.rename({'h_rot_j': 'h_pos'}
>>> xr.dot(rot_data2, pos_data, dims='h_pos')
ValueError: indexes along dimension 'x' are not equal
```

As a work-around, you should also assign the `h_pos` coordinate *values* to `rot_data2`, e.g.,

```
>>> rot_data2 = rot_data.rename({'h_rot_j': 'h_pos'})
>>> rot_data2.coords['h_pos'] = pos_data.h_pos
>>> xr.dot(rot_data2, pos_data, dims='h_pos')
<xarray.DataArray (time: 1000, h_rot_i: 3)>
array([[1.034348, 0.655469, 1.235536],
       [0.815916, 0.632311, 0.603557],
       [0.87191 , 0.54483 , 0.586762],
       ...,
       [0.629219, 0.716169, 0.721611],
       [0.517938, 0.440981, 0.649848],
       [0.763335, 0.624545, 0.370505]])
Dimensions without coordinates: time, h_rot_i
```

At this point, you probably also want to use `rename` and coordinate assignment to switch `h_rot_i` -> `h_pos`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader :).

Comment: thank you, I assumed I was doing something wrong when renaming and using dot didn't work, didn't occur to me that I could have encountered a bug! Just starting out with the library, I like the basic concept of xarray but in some cases the dim matching is still a bit confusing for me. Wouldn't it be better to tell the dot function which dims to combine, instead of renaming, which looks like changing the data, but actually just prepares it so the dot function works?

Comment: In case this helps anyone else: 
`This showed up for me as: ValueError: cannot align objects with join='exact' where index/labels/sizes are not equal along these coordinates (dimensions): 'X' ('X',)`
ds1 and ds2 had same X and Y datatypes and values. But ds1 X value was e.g., 1.300e3 and ds2 X value was 1300.